# How to get 16 months baby to drink milk again

Tags: toddler, milk

Our son was breastfed until around 6 months and then was put on formula milk.
He used to drink well until about 11 months when he started drinking less and less milk, and stopped completely about 3 months ago.
He eats very well and drinks juice and tea (we live in Japan, tea for babies is very popular). I also feed him 2 yoghurts a day to make up for the calcium missing from not drinking milk. We tried giving him normal milk too but he still refuses it.
I read this question [Toddler does not like to drink milk](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/17976/toddler-does-not-like-to-drink-milk)
but mine is a bit different in that I would like to try to get him to drink milk again. Would you please share some ways to do that? Or should I just accept this fact and give him substitutes for calcium and Vitamin D?

Comment: Is your son trying to maximise his suger intake?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. We try to avoid giving him much sugar except for the juice, and his yoghurts are plain(not sure about the amount of sugar in there). His meals are mostly rice or pasta with vegetables (carrots, potatoes, spinach, ...). He loves bananas too and oranges sometimes.

Comment: You can get calcium and vitamin D from a lot of other sources besides milk. It tends to be a very American thing to have children drink milk with everything and all the time for the "calcium" and "vitamin D". If your child is refusing to drink milk or formula, but eats a variety of other unprocessed foods, I would not be worried. You could add a liquid vitamin D to any drink if you must, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Rice and Pasta are quickly digested into glocose.  (digestion is even faster if low fat meal with little protein) It is very likely the yoghurt has added suger or sweeter (acts in same way in brain as suger).   Juice is high suger, and there is nothing good about "natural" suger, and unlike raw fruit there is no fiber to slow down the "suger rush".

Comment: Ian, thank you for the info, it is not the point of the question but I will keep it in mind!
Jcmack, it is the same in my country, and I guess I should stop thinking like that, thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry. Most cultures don't stress drinking milk once the baby has weaned. If you're not concerned about weight and your baby eats a nutrient dense and diverse diet, then I don't think you need to stress. There was a period where our baby did not want cows milk (recommended by doctors here after breast milk or formula) but she was tracking just fine on her weight chart and eating healthy otherwise so our doctor said it's fine. I am not a doctor however so if you are concerned, you should check with your pediatrician.

Answer (score 0):

Once my oldest kids went off of the bottle, they would not drink milk what so ever. I was able to get them to drink chocolate milk out of a cup, but it had to be made with syrup and milk. Other than that 15 years later, still will not drink milk unless it's syrup made chocolate milk.